# Loop in Rails view without line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, sass

I want to loop through an array of things and create a tab for each one. When I pull up the page, however, each one appears on a new line. I'm using Slim, though I think this would translate to any other tempting language.

I also have a reset.css loaded before anything else, but the breaks remain.

Slim:

```
p Your dashboard!
.tabs
  .tab-bar
    - TYPES.each do |type|
      .tab-item
        p
          = type.to_s
```

Scss:

```
.tabs {
  width: 80%;
  border-color: $slushie;
  .tab-bar {
    .tab-item{
      p {
        color: $white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a float:left; element onto the css element

```
tabs {
          float:left;
          width: 80%;
          border-color: $slushie;
          .tab-bar {
            .tab-item{
              p {
                color: $white;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: Helvetica;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using a `p` element which is normally a block element. You can override this using something like `display: inline;` (not that you will need to do this on your `.tab-item` div too). You could also float the `.tab-item` elements instead.

```
.tabs {
  width: 80%;
  border-color: $slushie;
  .tab-bar {
    .tab-item{
      display: inline;
      p {
        color: $white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        display: inline;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that and switched to an `a`. Are they usually block?

Comment: `a` is usually inline, whereas `div` and `p` are block.